# false errors suggested by neovim which is using nvchad on windows os

Tags: windows, clang, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUaAm.png)

this error is present only on window pc and not my ubuntu vm.

programm compiles fine and also runs good.

but i have no idea why and how the errors are  suggested

currently my guess is that the clangd lsp server is doing this which is present in lspconfig and mason in the nvchad.

you can ask me to provide specific detail about problem as you need.

i tired to reinstall nvchad. i tried to reinstall nvim tree-sitter. but is did not affect problem..

Comment: If you are using cmake, then it's likely you don't have compile_commands.json present, but if you are running a plain cpp project, then you probably don't have clang or llvm itself installed in windows. I am not sure if that is the solution because I have mine resolved a long time ago and I don't recall my solution, lmk if it doesn't work